# DjangoRestFramework: How to modify response provided by ModelViewSet?

Tags: json, django, web, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am writing a server with django rest framework.
Basically the ModelViewSet is working great. It generally respond a json like:

```
[{object1}, {object2}]
```

or

```
{object}
```

or with error

```
{"detail": error}
```

but now, I want the response to be like:

```
{"code": code, "data": [{object1}, {object2}]}
```

or

```
{"code": code, "data": {object}}
```

or with error

```
{"code": code}
```

To display a response code, and put the actual data in the data field.How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You should roll your own [renderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#custom-renderers) and [configure DRF to use it](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#setting-the-renderers).